# How to trigger one PS script from another after a set time, without blocking execution

Tags: powershell, release-management

Say I have a file `A.ps1` that calls `B.ps1`:

```
& "B.ps1"
```

I want the contents of B.ps1 to run after N seconds, without blocking A.ps1.  In this case, A.ps1 would finish immediately, and then the contents of B.ps1 would run after a set time.

How can this be achieved?

**Context**

We're leveraging Release Management to deploy builds with a powershell script.  Sometimes RM outputs logging data that we need into a `IR_ProcessAutoOutput` file - but this only gets generated once RM completes.  So I want to defer execution of the "GetLogs" script for ~20 seconds without blocking, allowing RM to complete and generate the IR_ProcessAutoOutput in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Start-Process`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848.aspx) instead of the call operator.

```
Start-Process 'powershell.exe' -ArgumentList '-File', 'B.ps1'
```

If you don't want the process to run in a different window add the parameter `-NoNewWindow`.

You could also run the second script as a [background job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878288%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
Start-Job -Scriptblock { & 'B.ps1' }
```

If you want `B.ps1` to start *after* `A.ps1` already terminated you'd need to create a scheduled task, though. Or add a delay at the beginning of `B.ps1`:

```
Start-Sleep -Seconds 20
...
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Ansgar, an alternative to `Start-Process` is scheduling a task instead.

Make sure the task gets deleted automatically after execution

```
# A.ps1 doing its thing, and then:
$DelayInSeconds = 5
$SchTaskProperties = @{
    # Invoke powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -File B.ps1
    Action   = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Id 0 -Execute powershell -Argument "-WindowStyle Hidden -File B.ps1" -WorkingDirectory 'C:\path\to\scripts'
    # Let it trigger in 5 seconds
    Trigger  = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At $([datetime]::Now.AddSeconds($DelayInSeconds)) -Once
    # Set task to be deleted after expiration, see below
    Settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -DeleteExpiredTaskAfter (New-TimeSpan -Seconds 0)
    # Make up unique task name
    TaskName = "MyTask $([guid]::NewGuid())"
}
# Give the Trigger an EndBoundary (2 minutes later) to make sure it expires and is deleted
$SchTaskProperties['Trigger'].EndBoundary = [datetime]::UtcNow.AddMinutes(2).ToString('s') + 'Z'

# Register the task    
Register-ScheduledTask @SchTaskProperties |Out-Null
# Do whatever else A.ps1 needs to
```